# How to increase font colour and font size of selected index in table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I need to implement this page as shown in image here for that I placed a table view and collection view but here if I select the particular category then how to make the selected font size to be larger and font colour needs to be changed as shown in image but after running app if I select the screen to open at that time first default it should be selected that is `What's New` and later it need to change to what I selected can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

**Here is my screen which designed to be like:**

[image]

**Here is my designed screen and in which issue in this:**

[image]

here is my code which I already tried

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesTableCell", for: indexPath)  as! categoriesTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == currentSelection {
    let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
    cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
    cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
    let underlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (item?.name)! , attributes: underlineAttribute)
            underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.cyan, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (item?.name?.characters.count)!))
            cell.categoriesProductsLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
    }
    else {
          let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
          print(item?.name)
          cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
          //cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Regular", size: 12)
          cell.categoriesProductsLabel.text = item?.name
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let previousSelection = self.currentSelection
    self.currentSelection = indexPath.row
    self.categoriesCollectionView.reloadData()
    print(indexPath.row)
    if previousSelection == 0 {
        sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
    else {
        let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelection, section: 0)
        self.sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [prevIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override setSelected method in your **categoriesTableViewCell** class like this and don't update in **cellForRowAt** or **didSelectRowAt**

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected{
        categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
        categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

     }else{
        categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Regular", size: 12)

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ovveride didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath both methods to change and restore original font size and color

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          //get cell with indexpath
  cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
    cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     //get cell with indexpath
     cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Regular", size: 12)

}
```

Comment: if this solution is not working then use same u posted but maintain cell referenece array or create different dequeue identifier for selected and not selected cells. reload all table in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

you have to update if condition and your code will also work as you want :-

Replace this one :-

```
if previousSelection == 0 {
    sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
else {
    let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelection, section: 0)
    self.sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [prevIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

with this one :-

```
    let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelection, section: 0)
    self.sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [prevIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
```